# Is there some difference in specifing an absolute path using concatenation vs path.resolve?

Tags: node.js

When specifying an absolute path, is there some difference between the following invocations?

```
__dirname + '/app'
```

vs

```
path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all the path functions, such as `path.resolve` and `path.join`, handle cross-platform differences on what seperator is used in between folders in paths gracefully. (`/` and `\`)

Those functions also handle double seperators, such as `folder1//folder2` gracefully.